# Collecting data from 3rd party RESTful API then rename giving the same name as it had at REST

Tags: rest, attributes, apache-nifi

I have managed to create a flow for which I have 2 InvokeHTTP Processors as one is connecting to the following URLs (sensitive data has been omitted)

```
https://api.xxxxxx.com/reports/v1/scheduledReports/download/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/2019-04-02T01:50:00Z.csv
https://api.xxxxxx.com/reports/v1/scheduledReports/download/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/2019-02-12T02:51:00Z.xxxxx_xxxxx.csv
https://api.xxxxxx.com/reports/v1/scheduledReports/download/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/2019-03-04T17:36:00Z.csv
```

The second is:

```
https://api.xxxxx.com/reports/v1/scheduledReports/download/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/2019-04-02T17:39:00Z.pdf
```

I have done it this way, as I was unable to find a way in the UpdateAttribute to rename the to .csv and .pdf 
simultaneously within the same UpdateAttribute. Whilst I am able to download the data with the correct file ext, I am now trying to find a way that I can produce the file to output with its original filename as it is at REST on the 3rd party RESTAp.  Any ideas please?

Comment: what does it mean `original filename as it is at REST on the 3rd party RESTApi` ? in your case what filename do you want to get?

Comment: So whilst it is at rest on the 3rd party APi one  file would be named:"Weekly_Evidence_History.csv" or "2019-04-02T01:50:00Z.csv"  names will change date depaendant however when the files land internally I get something like "14479678495574605.csv"

Comment: and the file name is in URL? `https://......./2019-04-02T17:39:00Z.pdf` and you want to get last part of url as filename?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Comment: you should have url in one of flowfile attributes. you could use UpdateAttribute with regular expression to extract filename from url. but beware the colon `:` not valid for filename...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you are having trouble with this. You cannot change the same attribute using a single `UpdateAttribute` processor, but you can drag as many *response* relationships from the `InvokeHTTP` processor as you like (most processors have only *failure* and *success* relationships, but `InvokeHTTP` is different because of the mechanics of HTTP request/response). Drag one *response* relationship to an `UpdateAttribute` processor that sets the **filename** to `${filename}.csv` and another that sets it to `${filename}.pdf`.

Comment: Hi there, This is what I have done and I have 2 InvokeHTTP requests one for .csv and the other for the .pdf and the UpdateAttributes that I have on each one of the InvokeHTTP keep that file ext by using ${filename}.csv & ${filename}.pdf

Comment: Does that mean you have achieved what you are trying to do or is there still a gap here?

Comment: Hi Andy, there is still a gap here. the files at rest have username "abcd1234.csv" and "abcd1234.pdf" but I am getting "1234567891011.csv" and "1234567891011.pdf" how do I keep the filename?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It looks like those are human-generated values (sequential numbering), but in another comment above, you say they have a value which looks like a timestamp (`14479678495574605.csv` resembles an epoch time with additional characters). Can you provide a screenshot of the data provenance event of a flowfile going through this processor?